# How to sync between github(master branch) and production server code after rollback is happened

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository and branch name master. We had deployment yesterday and went well. But today some reason I want to rollback the changes from production server. Here master branch code and production server code is not the same. How can get the older code in github branch?

Comment: Sync from github or to github ? But why this is different from a normal deploy, than deploy  your rollback ? Just commit the rollback

Comment: I've rollbacked the changes in production server. My question is, after rollback the code,  not in sync between github(master branch) and production server code. If want to see the rollback changes in github, how can check it?

Comment: If you do your rollback with `git revert`, which *adds a new commit*, all goes smoothly. If you do a rollback with `git reset`, which *drops commits off the end of a branch*, re-sync generally *brings those commits back* because Git repositories are built to add new commits, not drop them off the end. To drop commits from the end of six clones of a repository, you must do this kind of rollback six times.